# Why does ubuntu get slow after a period of time?

Tags: startup

I have used the ubuntu 11.04 for several months and it is much faster during the startup at first. But it takes much longer time to start after several months. Since I have turn off the system service such as apache2, mysql and so on and the situation doesn't change, I don't why this happens.

According to the advice of some guys, I have got the chart by using bootchar(I cannot post it here because of lack of reputation),
What should I do to shorten the startup time now? Should I stop some of them? I don't know how to analysis the chart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what causes the slowdown in your specific situation, but you might want to check out bootchart. Here is an article (first hit in duckduckgo.com) http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/measure-your-ubuntu-systems-boot-performance-with-boot-chart/
Bootchart gives you a graphical representation of the order of various boot time processes starting, how much CPU / (waiting for) disk they use. It is of most use if you have it installed on a clean system (as a reference), but it is definitely worth a try to give you more insight in what's going on during boot.

Comment: According to the your advice, I have got the chart by using bootchar(I cannot post it here because of lack of reputation), What should I do to shorten the startup time now? Should I stop some of them? I don't know how to analysis the chart. @jippie

Comment: Ideally you compare your chart with one in a little while and see how they differ. But you can check the various names of boot scripts on Internet already and see if you really need all of them. But this is a tricky job, you can easily make your system unusable if you turn off wrong scripts. At least you should be able now to figure out which job takes the most time and where potentially the most saving can be found.

Comment: Put the chart into a Google Doc, share it with anyone who has the URL then post the URL here.