# Is the absence of a boot screen ever going to be a problem?

Tags: 12.04, boot

When I boot my computer, I've never seen a boot screen. I only get a purple or black background for about 45-60 seconds (which seems abnormally long to me, considering I have a fairly modern system and when the process of shutting down takes about 6 seconds tops). Is this normal? If not, any suggestions on a possible fix or what could be causing it? I see it sometimes when I shut down, but is it normal that I never see this image on boot up:

[image]

Comment: Shutdown is fast because slow processes are dealt a swift kill after a timeout. Booting will be slow as long as you store the os on a harddrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the timeout for the Grub menu is set to zero. You can have a look by installing Grub Customizer. The link below gives some great help as well as showing you how to install it. Good luck. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10340183

Comment: The timeout was set to zero. I suppose that's the default option. The Grub Customizer helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be a problem, because holding `Shift` during initial boot on swaps the purple screen for the text console where all sorts of messages are logged.

`Shift` varies a bit per distribution, I believe it is for Ubuntu.

The time required to boot is totally dependend on a number of things, [this answer explains how you can figure out what your time is being spent on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112517/why-does-ubuntu-get-slow-after-a-period-of-time/112523#112523).